# Draggable is not working getting the uncaught reference error

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add a draggable to the frames but it is not working and throwing the below exception

created the Frames using iframe but could not apply the draggable for my frames.Please help me to solve my problem.

```
 Uncaught ReferenceError: HSplitter is not defined at HTMLDivElement.onmousedown
```

Please find my code below:

```js
 var HSplitter = {
 
     mouseDown: function  (_split, event)
     {
        if(!this.isToggle)
  {
      this.parent = _split.parentNode.parentNode; //td
   this.currentSplit = _split;
   this.splitterWidth = $(this.currentSplit).getWidth();
            this.splitPointX = Event.pointerX(event);
   this.drag = true;
   this.splitDiv = $(this.parent).getElementsByClassName("HSplitDiv")[0];

            //min width of a parent container couldn't be less than splitter width.
            if( this.minWidth < this.splitterWidth )
                this.minWidth = this.splitterWidth;
            this.mouseOver(_split, event);
            $(this.splitDiv).setStyle({paddingRight: '0px'}); //reset padding


            this._splitDivOverflow(true); //set overflow to ON
        }
    },
    mouseUp: function (split, event)
    {
     if(!this.isToggle)
  {
   this.drag = false;

            this._setDynamicOverflow();
        }
     },
       };
```

```html
         <head>
        <link href="/Work/css/tab_style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href="D:/cnsdi-projects/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Work/css/1.10.19/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Work/css/1.10.19/bootstrap.min.css">

        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"> 
       </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/Work/js/3.3.7/bootstrap.min.js"> 
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <div class="tab-content" >
        <div id="sectionA" class="tab-pane fade in active" style="overflow:visible;"> 
        <iframe  scrolling="yes" src="pg1.html" name="leftside"  style="position:absolute;top:140px;left:0%;width:25%;height:100%;border: none;" ></iframe>
  <div class="split1" onselect="return false;" unselectable="on" onmouseup="HSplitter.mouseUp(this, event);" onmousedown="HSplitter.setMaxMinWidth('-1','-1'); HSplitter.mouseDown(this, event);" style="left: auto;">
  <span class="collapse l-splt-btn" onclick="HSplitter.splitToggle(this);"></span>
  </div>
  <iframe src="pg2.html" name="rightside" scrolling="yes" style="position:absolute;top:140px;left:25%;width:75%;height:50%;border: none;"></iframe>
  <div class="split"><div class="vcollapse d-splt-btn" onclick="VSplitter.splitToggle(this);" toppaneheight="50%" id="idx1320192_vspltbtn"></div></div>
  <iframe src="pg3.html" name="rightside" scrolling="yes" style="position:absolute;top:450px;left:25%;width:75%;height:30%;border: none;"></iframe>
        </div>
         </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/utils/Draggable.min.js"></script>
```

Please input this code in your site header and if it doesn't work , let me know.
Thank you!